# Accessing localhost from other computer without the ip

Tags: wireless, networking, server, apache2

Lately, I've been thinking about a thing that made me curious: I've created a simple website with PHP that has some things that are useful for my family and the people who live in my house.

I use apache2, so I can access to my webpage with "localhost" and they can access through my IP, but I was wondering if there's a way to use like a *"private domain"* only available for the computers in my network.
What I mean is: is it possible to when, for example, somebody in the network goes to `http://home` to redirect them to my IP so they can access this webpage I created in my personal machine?
I was also wondering if it's possible to put this "little website" with my router or something like this, so it isn't necessary to have my PC on...

I know there's a name for all of this that I'm asking for, but I'm not very used with this network things in Ubuntu, so I'm a newbie here.
Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either (1) you can add static name in your router DNS table
This means you can add a line that will tell every PC on the lan that "home" is that one ip.

or (2) you set up a DNS server in one of your PC of your lan.
The PC running the DNS server must always be on, registered as DNS server in the dhcp configuration of the router,
in the DNS server configuration you add a line that make correspond "home" for the ip of your machine.

Comment: FWIW, dnsmasq is easy to configure - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dnsmasq